# How is an array stored in memory in this program?

Tags: c, arrays, memory, memory-management, out-of-memory

How is an array stored in memory in this program? What happened here?
How to understand this behaviour in c?(is it undefine/unspecified/implementation behaviour).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char a[5] = "world";
char b[16] = "haii how are you";

printf("string1 %s\nstring2 %s\n", a, b);

return 0;
}
```

output:

```
user@toad:~$ gcc -Wall simple.c
user@toad:~$ ./a.out 
string1 world
string2 haii how are youworld
user@toad:~$
```

but it is work fine.

```
char a[5] = "world";
char b[17] = "haii how are you?";
```

Comment: Undefined behavior because printf `%s` takes a string, but `a` and `b` aren't strings: They aren't `'\0'` terminated.

Comment: Remember that size strings require is *number of characters + 1 for nul character*. Just remove the size from array definition and compiler calculates the correct size: `char a[] = "world"; // allocates 6 elements`.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Did you read the Title? ==>> `How is an array stored in memory in this program?` How does this make it DUP? Where asked the OP that?

Comment: @Michi the title does not reflect the actual problem OP shows in the question body

Answer (score 3):

Both of the string in the first snippet is not null terminated. They are just character arrays, not null terminated string literals.
`printf` with `%s` specifier expects a null terminated string as its argument. Passing wrong type of argument will invoke undefined behavior.

`printf` write the string to the standard output till it encounters a `'\0'` character. In case of absence of `'\0'` it will read past the array. Since `a` and `b` are not null terminated, it could be the case that after writing `b` to the terminal `printf` continues to search for `'\0'` and it founds it after the string `a`.

Comment: OPs Title says `How is an array stored in memory in this program?`. I'm agree that the code is not the same with the Title, but what would one Answer if the Title will be the same, but the code will bi [Like this](http://ideone.com/AXClWb)? Because somehow I believe that, this is what the OP was asking

Comment: @Michi; I didn't get your point. Could give some more information what you are asking about?

Comment: The OP needs in the Title something and ask in its Topic something else. is hard to know the real Question here :)

Answer (score 2):

As per the C11 standard (6.7.9 Initialization).

```
    EXAMPLE 8
The declaration
char s[] = "abc", t[3] = "abc";

defines ‘‘plain’’ char array objects s and t whose elements are initialized with character string literals.

This declaration is identical to
char s[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' },
t[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };

The contents of the arrays are modifiable. On the other hand, the declaration
char *p = "abc";
defines p with type ‘‘pointer to char’’ and initializes it to point to an object with type ‘‘array of char’’
with length 4 whose elements are initialized with a character string literal. If an attempt is made to use p to
modify the contents of the array, the behavior is undefined.
```

As per this for you

```
char a[6] = "world";
char b[17] = "haii how are you";
```

At the end of the "world" and "haii how are you" the '\0' is not  added. So while using printf it searches for '\0' and prints both 'a' and 'b'.

Comment: "At the end of the "world" and "haii how are you" the '\0' is not added. So while using printf it searches for '\0' and prints both 'a' and 'b'." --
That's not guaranteed, C does not make any promises that these arrays follow after another.

Comment: Arrays declared within a function (and not declared with the 'static' keyword; this would make them a global) are going to be put on the stack. So it will be one above the other.

Comment: The C standard has no notion of what a "stack" is.

Answer (score 1):

The code is not correct. Some compilers do not want to compile it:

```
> clang++ test.cxx 
test.cxx:5:14: error: initializer-string for char array is too long
        char a[5] = "world";
                    ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Maybe your compiler just ignores array size, assigning the address of string constant to it and keeping null character at the end.

Comment: Why should not be correct? [Why should be this Wrong](http://ideone.com/AXClWb)?

Comment: Yep, for me this is a compiler-bug, at least if this also occurs with *clang* and not *clang++* -- I don't know the C++ spec but I'm pretty sure the code @Michi linked is correct C99

Comment: `C99 6.7.8/14: An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive characters of the character string literal (including the terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the elements of the array.`

Comment: No, it fails with clang++ only, clang compiles it perfectly. Seems to be one of the differences between C and C++?

Comment: @AntonMalyshev Same in C11 6.7.9/14  `An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF−8 string
literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive bytes of the string literal (including the
terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the
elements of the array.`

Comment: @AntonMalyshev Yep, seems so. g++ also fails

Comment: @Michi C99-standard is not the C++ standard:
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf
Section 8.5.2/2

Comment: Wrapped it all up in my answer, plus adding memory layout.

Comment: @larkey True, but this is a `C` question and not `C++` one.

Comment: @Michi Yep, but I thought you meant it as a reply to Anton's comment on it veing a C/C++ difference :)

Answer (score 1):

```
char a[5] = "world";
```

World has 5 characters inside and if you initialize it, you must indicate that your string is ended by null character --> \0

If you define it like that

```
char a[6] = "world";
```

Then compiler put the null character at the end for you.

For your question, most compilers don't allow you define `char a[5] = "world"` but it seems that your memory is allocated like this

[ h ] [ a ] [ i ] [ i ] [   ] [ h ] [ o ] [ w ] [   ] [ a ] [ r ] [ e ] [   ] [ y ] [ o ] [ u ] [ w ] [ o ] [ r ] [ l ] [ d ] [ \0 ]

Then last point you must know that %s prints the character set until it reaches null character --> \0

Comment: No, it's unlikely that there's a \0 just directly at the end -- in my case the layout is actually "world\x7f\0" -- \7f is just not printed.

Answer (score 1):

> How is an array stored in memory in this program?

First notice that your program is undefined behavior as you call `printf` with a char array and not a string since there isn't room for the zero-termination in the two arrays. For instance you only reserve 5 chars for `a` and `world` takes up all 5, i.e. no room for the termination.

A strict person would say that due to UB it makes no sense to speculate about what is going on - with UB anything can happen.

But if we do it anyway then it is likely as described below.

The answer would depend on your system as `c` doesn't specify all aspects of storing data. It is specified that an array must be in contiguous memory but exactly how and where that memory is located, is beyond the standard.

From the output you have, it seems that your system have located it like this:

```
haii how are youworld
^               ^
b               a
```

You can't know what is after the last `d`.

However, when you print `a` you get the output `world` which tells us that "by luck" there is a '\0' just after the last `d`.

```
haii how are youworld'\0'
^               ^      ^
b               a      "luck"
```

So printing `a` will give `world` and printing `b` will give `haii how are youworld`.

Your code should be:

```
char a[6] = "world";
char b[17] = "haii how are you";
```

to make room for the termination of each string and so that your memory layout would be

```
haii how are you'\0'world'\0'
^                   ^      
b                   a
```

**Notice:** The '\0' that you got "by luck" is probably because your system initializes all memory assigned to your program to zero at start up.

Comment: No, it's unlikely that there's a `\0` just directly at the end -- in my case the layout is actually `"world\x7f\0"` -- `\7f` is just not printed.

Comment: @larkey - It is indeed likely as many systems zero initializes at start up. But it isn't something you can count on. Your system may not do it that way. Others may. As I wrote: It's system dependent. Also you can't trust that 0x7f isn't printed - on my system it would be.

Comment: But you assume that the `'\0'` got there by luck -- while it may just have been eg. a "\7f\0". It's just that you do simply not notice this. It's likely that it works but unlikely that the byte just after the `'d'` is a `'\0'`. I tried on all my machines and I often got 1/2 bytes of garbage (that's not printed though) followed by the terminating '\0' byte.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by others, while the array declaration itself is completely conformant (you declare an array of chars, not a string):

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal, optionally
>   enclosed in braces. Successive characters of the character string literal (including the
>   terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the
>   elements of the array.

(Section 6.7.8/14 of C99 standard [n1256.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf); thanks to @Michi for pointing out the paragraph)

Trying to print these using `%s` is undefined though. However you can specify the length of characters to print in the format string (`%.5s`) -- this way you'd be ok again.

---

Concerning the memory layout: C does not make many promises about how the memory is laid out actually. The only thing I can find is:

> An array type describes a contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects with a
>   particular member object type, called the element type.
>   36) Array types are
>   characterized by their element type and by the number of elements in the array. An
>   array type is said to be derived from its element type, and if its element type is T, the
>   array type is sometimes called ‘‘array of T’’. The construction of an array type from
>   an element type is called ‘‘array type derivation’’.

(Section 6.2.5/20 of C99 standard [n1256.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf))

---

Note however, that in C++ even the code

```
char test[5] = "12345";
```

is illegal:

> There shall not be more initializers than there are array elements. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> char cv[4] = "asdf";    // error
> ```
>
> is ill-formed since there is no space for the implied trailing ’\0’. *— end example* ]

(Section 8.5.2/2 of C++ 14 standard [n4296.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf))