# Is it undefined behavior if the destination string in strcat function is not null terminated?

Tags: c, string, language-lawyer, strcat

The following program

```
// Code has taken from http://ideone.com/AXClWb
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE1 5
#define SIZE2 10
#define SIZE3 15

int main(void){
    char a[SIZE1] = "Hello";
    char b[SIZE2] = " World";
    char res[SIZE3] = {0};

    for (int i=0 ; i<SIZE1 ; i++){
        res[i] = a[i];
    }

    strcat(res, b);
    printf("The new string is:  %s\n",res);
    return 0;
}
```

has well defined behavior. As per the requirement, source string `b` is null terminated. But what would be the behavior if the line

```
char res[SIZE3] = {0};  // Destination string
```

is replaced with

```
char res[SIZE3];
```

Does standard says explicitly about the destination string to be null terminated too?

Comment: I think `strcat` start searching for the `null terminator` into the `res` string before to concatenate the string, so it is UB.

Comment: @LPs What exactly is UB? Doesn't this line `char res[SIZE3] = {0};` initialize `res` to `15` ZERO's?

Comment: @Michi Read another look at the question: OP wants to know if `char res[SIZE3];` instead.

Comment: @LPs I noticed to late that. This was my [CODE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38891031/how-is-an-array-stored-in-memory-in-this-program/38891207?noredirect=1#comment65144649_38891207) in another Question.

Comment: `UB` = Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @haccks that was the reason why that `for` is present there. [If you remove](http://ideone.com/vCUCW8) that `for` and you will replace it with `strcpy`, even if you say `char res[SIZE3] = {0};` is still UB, because `strcpy` search for that `'\0'` too and `char a[SIZE1] = "Hello";` doesn't have it. This is the major problem when dealing with `strcpy` and `strcat` many they don't really know when should use `strcpy` or `strcat` .... or both.

Comment: The way `strcat` works is that it iterates through `dest` string characters until it reaches the null character in `dest`, and then appends `src` characters until it reaches the null character in `src`. It depends on `dest` being null terminated. Concatenating multiple strings is therefore relatively expensive, i.e. the function always starts from the beginning of the destination string. It would be cool if `strcat` returned the pointer to the last (null) character to avoid this, but unfortunately it just returns `dest` again.

Comment: @Groo: I find myself hard-pressed to think of many use cases for `strcat` as defined.  A variation of strcpy that accepted "start" and "one-past" pointers for the destination buffer and returned the either the location of the trailing zero (if written) or the one-past pointer of the destination (if full) would seem much more useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** Yes.

---

*Since this is a language-lawyer question, let me add my two cents to it.*

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.24.3.1/2 (*emphas is mine*)

> ```
> char *strcat(char * restrict s1,const char * restrict s2);
> ```
>
> The `strcat` function appends a copy of the string pointed to by `s2` (including the
>   terminating null character) **to the end of the string pointed to by `s1`.**  The initial character
>   of `s2` overwrites the null character at the end of `s1`.[...]

and, by definition, a *string* ***is*** null-terminated, quoting §7.1.1/1

> A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters **terminated by and including the first null
>   character.**

So, if the source `char` array is not null-terminated (i.e., not a *string*), `strcat()` may very well go beyond the bounds in search of *the end* which  invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

As per your question, `char res[SIZE3];` being an automatic local variable, will contain indeterminate value, and if used as the destination of `strcat()`, will invoke UB.

Comment: What does this line `char res[SIZE3] = {0};` ?

Comment: Damn you right...O missed that LoL Sorry about that :))

Comment: @Michi happens, no worries, let's clean up, shall we?

Comment: I don't know why I was thinking in this way that *a is not necessarily null terminated*, but standard says it explicitly that it is. I should have searched for this before asking this question. Good catch BTW.

Comment: @haccks Sometimes all we need is an extra pair of eyes to fill the gaps. happy to help, sir. :)

Answer (score 3):

I think [man](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) *explicitly* says that

> Description
>
> The strcat() function appends the src string to the dest string, **overwriting the terminating null byte ('\0') at the end of dest**, and then adds a terminating null byte. The strings may not overlap, and the dest string must have enough space for the result. If dest is not large enough, program behavior is unpredictable; buffer overruns are a favorite avenue for attacking secure programs.

<sup>Enphasis mine</sup>

BTW I think `strcat` starts searching for the `null terminator` into the dest string before to concatenate the new string, so it is obviously UB, as far as `dest` string has automatic storage.

In the proposed code

```
for (int i=0 ; i<SIZE1 ; i++){
    res[i] = a[i];
}
```

Copy `5` chars of `a` and not the null terminator to `res` string, so other bytes from `5` to `14` are uninitialized.

Standard also says about safaer implementation strcat-s

> **K.3.7.2.1 The strcat_s function**
>
> Synopsis
>
> ```
>     #define _ _STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1_ _ 1
>       #include <string.h>
>       errno_t strcat_s(char * restrict s1,
>            rsize_t s1max,
>            const char * restrict s2);
> ```
>
> **Runtime-constraints**
>
> 2 Let *m* denote the value **s1max - strnlen_s(s1, s1max)** upon entry to
>   **strcat_s**.

We can see that `strlen_s` always return them valid size for the `dest` buffer. From my point of view this implementation was introduced to avoid the UB of the question.

Comment: `so other bytes from 5 to 14 are uninitialized.`. What does this line `char res[SIZE3] = {0};` ?

Comment: @Michi It is raleted to the question that says: _if I use `char res[SIZE3];` instead_?

Comment: I was concentrate on the CODE itself :))

Answer (score 2):

If you leave `res` uninitialized then, after the copying `a` into `res` (in for loop), there's no NUL terminator in `res`. So, the behaviour of `strcat()` is undefined if the destination string doesn't contain a NUL byte.

Basically `strcat()` requires both of its arguments to be *strings* (i.e. both must contain the terminating NUL byte). Otherwise, it's [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). This 
is obvious from the description of `strcat()`:

[*§7.23.3.2, strcat() function*](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.3.1)

> The strcat function appends a copy of the **string pointed to by s2**
>   (including the terminating null character) to the end of the **string
>   pointed to by s1**. The initial character of s2 overwrites the null
>   character at the end of s1.

(emphasis mine).

Comment: `a` is not copied to `res`, its `b` and it is null terminated.

Comment: I was talking about the copying done in the for loop, where 5 bytes are copied into `res`, leaving it without the NUL terminator. Hence, the subsequent `strcat()` results in UB.

Answer (score 1):

If `char res[SIZE3];` is on the **stack**, it'll have random/undefined stuff in it.
You'll never know whether there'll be a zero byte within `res[SIZE3]`, so **yes**, `strcat`ting to that is undefined.

If `char res[SIZE3];` is an **uninitialized global**, it'll be *all zeros*, which will make it behave as an *empty c-string*, and `strcat`ing to it will be safe (as long as SIZE3 is large enough for what you're appending).