# C: Writing 4 bytes into a region of size 3 overflows the destination?

Tags: c, strcpy, null-terminated

My simple C program is as follows. Initially, I've defined variable `buf1` with 3 char.

I don't have any problem with 2 char such as `AB` or `XY`

```
user@linux:~/c# cat buff.c; gcc buff.c -o buff; echo -e '\n'; ./buff
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
        char buf1[3] = "AB";
        printf("buf1 val:  %s\n", buf1);
        printf("buf1 addr: %p\n", &buf1);
        strcpy(buf1,"XY");
        printf("buf1 val:  %s\n", buf1);
}

buf1 val:  AB
buf1 addr: 0xbfe0168d
buf1 val:  XY
user@linux:~/c#
```

Unfortunately, when I add 3 char such as `XYZ`, I'm getting the following error message when compiling the program.

```
buff.c:8:2: warning: ‘__builtin_memcpy’ writing 4 bytes into a region of size 3 overflows the destination [-Wstringop-overflow=]
  strcpy(buf1,"XYZ");
```

Isn't `XYZ` considered as 3 bytes? Why does the error message said `4 bytes` instead of `3 bytes`

```
user@linux:~/c# cat buff.c; gcc buff.c -o buff; echo -e '\n'; ./buff
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
        char buf1[3] = "AB";
        printf("buf1 val:  %s\n", buf1);
        printf("buf1 addr: %p\n", &buf1);
        strcpy(buf1,"XYZ");
        printf("buf1 val:  %s\n", buf1);
}buff.c: In function ‘main’:
buff.c:8:2: warning: ‘__builtin_memcpy’ writing 4 bytes into a region of size 3 overflows the destination [-Wstringop-overflow=]
  strcpy(buf1,"XYZ");
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


buf1 val:  AB
buf1 addr: 0xbfdb34fd
buf1 val:  XYZ
Segmentation fault
user@linux:~/c#
```

Comment: You're forgetting the **null terminator** which is the 4th byte!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're forgetting that C strings are null-terminated. The *sizeof* `"AB"` is 3 and *sizeof* `"XYZ"` is 4, due to the implicit terminating byte. (The type of the *string literal* `"AB"` is `char[3]` and the type of `"XYZ"` is `char[4]`.)

Had you not specified any length for `buf1`, it would also had been sized 3 bytes long:

```
char buf1[] = "AB";  // here exactly the same as char buf1[3] = "AB";
```

The memory layout would be

```
buf1
  v
  +-------+-------+-------+
  |  [0]  |  [1]  |  [2]  |
  +-------+-------+-------+
  |  'A'  |  'B'  |  '\0' |
  +-------+-------+-------+
```

---

Now, `strcpy` copies the terminating null character ([C11 7.24.2.3p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.2.3p2)):

> 2. The `strcpy` function copies the string pointed to by `s2` (**including the terminating null character**) into the array pointed to by `s1`. If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.

which means that 4 bytes are copied in total, but there are space for only 3 characters, therefore the code has **undefined behaviour** and the compiler produces the diagnostics messages. [C11 7.1.4 Use of library functions p.2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.4):

> [...] If a function argument is described as being an array, the pointer actually passed to the function shall have a value such that all address computations and accesses to objects (that would be valid if the pointer did point to the first element of such an array) are in fact valid.[...]

In the actual code the implicit access to the `buf1[3]` is in fact **not valid**.

Memory layout after `strcpy`:

```
buf1
  v
  +-------+-------+-------+-------+
  |  [0]  |  [1]  |  [2]  |  ???  |
  +-------+-------+-------+-------+
  |  'X'  |  'Y'  |  'Z'  |  '\0' |
  +-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

The reason why the warning comes from `__builtin_memcpy` is because the C compiler heavily optimized this code - it replaced the `strcpy` of a string of known length with `memcpy` of known length as `memcpy` would be generating more efficient code.

---

And finally, you *can* fit 3 characters into `char buf1[3];` by using `strncpy`, but the buffer cannot fit the terminating null character, and therefore it cannot be printed using `printf("%s")`, but you can print it with specifying explicit field width that is less than or equal to the length of the array - however the printed out value would be padded:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char buf1[3] = "AB";
    printf("buf1 val:  >%-3s<\n", buf1);
    printf("buf1 addr: %p\n", &buf1);
    strncpy(buf1, "XYZ", 3);
    printf("buf1 val:  >%-3s<\n", buf1);
}
```

And compiling, running it:

```
% gcc strncpy.c -Wall -Wextra
% ./a.out
buf1 val:  >AB <
buf1 addr: 0x7ffd7f6aecc5
buf1 val:  >XYZ<
```

but there is one extra space character printed after `AB`

Answer (score 0):

If you glance at implementation(s) of `strcpy`, you see that it depends on `null character`.

```
char *strcpy(char *d, const char *s)
{
   char *saved = d;
   while (*s != '\0')
   {
       *d++ = *s++;
   }
   *d = 0;
   return saved;
}
```

So, for `char arr[3]`, if you try to put three characters sequence, you overwrite on `'\0'`. Moreover, it may iterate through forever causing stack overflow. [A character sequence without null terminator gives rise to also undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38893740/4990642).

Answer (score 0):

[7.24.2.3p2 on strcpy:](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.2.3p2)

> The strcpy function copies the string pointed to by s2 (including the
>   terminating null character) into the array pointed to by s1.

3 chars + '\0' == 4 chars

You'll also get 4 from:

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof "ABC");
```

as string literals are basically anonymous char-array literals with static storage, basically equivalent to:

```
 static char const __anonymous[]="ABC"; /*the size gets inferred*/
```

or

```
 (char const[]){"ABC"};
```

(with a historical caveat about the `const` which isn't really there, but for all intents and purposes you should pretend it is)